# Python скрипты не работают в windows

Tags: python, cmd

Пытаюсь открыть скрипт Python в CMD, он не запускается и выводит лишь строку "Python", которой в коде нет в принципе. Сначала думал может быть в коде проблемы, но после этого написал простую операцию сложения

```py
a = 5
b = 4
c = a+b
print(c)
```

После попыток запуска опять просто появляется строка python и ничего не работает, результат вывода прилагаю в скриншоте
В Linux в то же время всё отлично работает, но суть состоит в том что нужно писать скрипт именно под Windows

p.s.
Сильно не пинайтесь, новичок в Python.
[image: результат вывода:]

Comment: используйте `py` вместо `python3`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё заработало

Comment: На здоровье! Смотрите, `python3` - команда для POSIX ОС. Если вы сами ничего не меняли в Windows она не сработает. Когда будете работать под linux'ами, то там используется именно `python3` и `python2` для различных версий языка

Comment: @Dmitry а еще можно сделать так как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423685/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/1423804#1423804)

Answer (score 0):

На Linux и MacOS Python вызывается командами `Python3` или `Python` ( В зависимости от установленной версии ).

Стандартный вызов состоит из `py name.py` - Должно сработать.

Comment: `Python3` и `Python`??? может быть, всё-таки `python3` и `python`?