# Отображение в командной строке

Tags: python, cmd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня довольно обычная проблема, как мне думается. Командой в cmd должно запускать скрипт, а вместо этого выводит одно слово:

```
python
```

что может быть не так?

[image: должен срабатывать скрипт, но постоянно пишет одно слово, я вначале пути обучения, памагити!]

Comment: Используйте py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю дело в том что, у вас python "не совсем" установлен.

Если у вас Windows 10 то попробуйте просто ввести в cmd `python`, должен открыться Microsoft Store.

[image]

Нажмите на кнопку *получить*.