# Powershell и VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, powershell

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]введите сюда описание изображения[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Установил pshell, чтобы запускать несколько name.py сразу без использования VS code. После перезагрузки компа прямо из терминала pshell кидает в VS code и уже там запускается name.py.Подскажите,что можно сделать?
P.S.Я новичок в программировании (сильно новичок),поэтому ответьте как идиоту)))[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы спрашиваете. Pshell - это вы так powershell называете? Можно со скриншотами? Какие команды и куда вы пишете, что у вас открывается...

Comment: Добавил скрин.Да,pshell сократил просто.Открываю терминал powershell и ввожу команду start-process,тут же открывается VS code,от имени админа,хотя он закрыт, и скрипт запускается уже из VS code. До перезагрузки после  этой же команды запускался консольно.

Comment: А где "скрипт запускается"? На скрине видно просто открытый VSC и все. Скорее всего `start-process` ведет себя как дабл-клик по файлу в проводнике, а у вас VSC выбран как приложение по умолчанию для .py - и это нормально. Откуда появилась идея использовать `start-process`? По идее ведь надо `python путь\до\файла.py`. (И PS для этого не обязательно использовать.)

Comment: Он точно запускается,на скрине не видно.Идея start-process появилась после бессонной ночи и попыток запустить код на виртуальной машине на Ubunte 22.04.Нагуглил,в общем. Про "PS не обязательно" не знал.

Comment: Добавил скрин команды через python,тоже ничего.Ни через стандартный терминал,ни через powershell

Comment: Значит питон не установлен, или не добавлен в PATH. (Майкрософт сделали программу-заглушку, которая должна говорить "поставь питон", а вместо этого почему-то просто печатает "Python" в терминал.)

Comment: Добавлял в переменные PATH.Папку /python/scripts.Её же надо?Да и установлен он у меня.

Comment: Не ее, а папку где лежит `python.exe`. PATH - для экзешников.

Comment: Не помогает, тот же ответ:"python"

Comment: Что-то не так сделали. Либо консоль не перезапустили после добавления в PATH, либо криво добавили. Если перезапуск не помогает, покажите скрин настроек PATH.

Comment: Добавил скрин.А в коменты  можно прикрепить скрин или только в топик?

Comment: Только в топик. В коммент можно ссылку, если загрузить на какой-то сторонний сайт. Покажите еще скрин содержимого этой папки, и вывод `gcm python` тоже.

Comment: Добавил скрины...

Comment: В общем,спасибо тебе огромное,Святой Чёрный Кот, я нашёл проблему.Программа открытия по умолчанию изменилась на VScode.Вернул на Python и всё заработало.Я действительно не очень умный, по ходу.

Comment: Не, то что VSC был программой по умолчанию - это наоборот нормально и удобно. Оно и без этого должно работать. Попробуйте в PATH подвинуть свою строку в начало списка.

Comment: А сразу несколько процессов одного скрипта запустить можно через неё?

Comment: И подскажите,если не трудно,как здесь указать,что вопрос решён?

Comment: Через нее - через кого? Чтобы можно было отметить как решенный, нужно чтобы кто-то запостил "ответ" (кнопка снизу - можете сами), и потом нажать галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1423804/507516