# Создал бота запустил а пишет просто python и всё

Tags: python, discord, бот

[image: вот это пишет]
[image: код]
написал бота на пайтон для дискорда и пишет при активации просто патон

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1379952/178576)

Comment: [еще дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423685/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)